# Limitation of TextView on Android

Tags: android, textview

I want to set TextView max line 2 and show "..." in the line middle.
My layout xml as below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

But it show as below:

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnop
```

It show 2 lines, but it doesn't show any "..." at middle or end.
How can I modify it?

Comment: ellipsize works on 1 line only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `android:ellipsize="end"`.

> ```
> <TextView
> android:id="@+id/text"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:gravity="center"
> android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
> android:ellipsize="end" <-----change it to end
> android:maxLines="2"
> android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`android:ellipsize` will work only when there's not enough space to display the whole text of the `TextView`. In your case, you've set `android:layout_width` to `fill_parent` and the text is not long enough, so no ellipsize is being used. Change the `android:layout_width` to some small amount of `dip` and you'll see the difference. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [android:ellipsize property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) on the TextView as required (probably to 'end').